# Specific and general acid catalysis

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nomenclature

What is the rationalization for calling reactions with rates independent of pH but dependent on the concentration of a particular acid catalyst under "general" acid catalysis, and pH dependent reactions under "specific" acid catalysis ?

It would seem to me that the pH-independent reactions would be better considered to be under "specific" acid catalysis given as they are catalysed by a specific species.

Answer (score 1):

I have wondered about this too. Although I could be wrong it is reasonable to assume (or at least handy to keep as a reminder) that the term "special" refers to the fact that compound is protonated in a very specific state, namely before the actual reaction occurs. General acid catalysis can happen both before the reaction or at any time during the reaction (i.e. in some transition state), whatever is likely in some range around the pH of the acid. Hence it is more general version of the special case mentioned above.

Comment: => specific acid catalysis is specific in so far as protonation occurs "specifically" in the transition state...not totally convinced but this seems plausible.

Comment: @J.LS Before the transition state. I agree that it is not totally clear that this is the meaning but it seems very plausible. If anyone knows what the actual reason is, feel free to edit this answer of course. It is provisional.

Comment: Hah, of course, it's still the other way round from being intuitive. How is before the transition state a "specific state" ?

Comment: @J.LS It is in the sense that the general mechanism can be during the transition state OR before the transition state. In other words SAC is a special case of GAC. That is what I mean. :)

Comment: "SAC is a special case of GAC"; that's simply not the case as I understand it; specific acid catalysis is not general acid catalysis because there is a pH dependence across the pH range. If you add some examples/sources to your answer it would really help !